# Show this function is Lebesgue-measurable, $f(x)=\sin(x)$ if $\sin(x)\in\mathbb Q$, else $f(x)=\cos^2(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \sin x,  & \text{if $\sin x\in \Bbb{Q}$} \\
> \cos^2x, & \text{if $\sin x\notin \Bbb{Q}$}
> \end{cases}$
>   Is $f(x)$ measurable over $[0,\pi/2]$ ?

I think it is measurable, but I have no idea how to prove it. Could you please give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: What is the measure?

Comment: Lebesgue measurable. Sorry for ambiguity.

Comment: One approach is showing that $\{x:\sin(x)\in\mathbb Q\}$ is countable and that a function equal almost everywhere to a measurable function is measurable.

Comment: @Ivo Terek (can't comment on deleted answer): Can't you just change $\mathbb Q$ in your answer to $\sin^{-1}(\mathbb Q)$?  This set is still countable, hence measurable.  (Or for overkill, $\sin$ is Borel measurable and $\mathbb Q$ is Borel.)

Comment: I was thinking of using that composite of Borel maps are again Borel. That'll do, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $$f(x) = (\sin x)(\chi_{\Bbb Q}\circ\sin)(x)+(\cos^2x)(\chi_{\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q}\circ\sin)(x). $$ These characteristic functions are Borel-measurable because both $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ are Borel sets. The functions $x\mapsto \sin x$ and $x\mapsto \cos^2x$ are continuous, hence Borel-measurable. Since sum, composites and products of Borel-measurable functions are again Borel-measurable, we conclude that $f$ is Borel-measurable. Hence $f$ is Lebesgue-measurable.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot this obvious trick.

Comment: Can I write $f(x)=(sinx)\chi_{sin^{-1}\Bbb{Q}}+...$?

Comment: Yes, you can, no worries.